# Is the default layout folder necessary when having layout-port and layout-land?

Tags: android, android-layout

My app uses a specific layout depending on the screen orientation `layout-port` and `layout-land` and I don't currently use `layout`. Reading the documentation the developers mentioned that we shouldn't make assumptions about the default orientation because some devices might have a default orientation of `landscape`.

Is it safe then to not include a `layout` folder and only have `layout-land` and `layout-port` ?

Answer (score 2):

Build scripts may need it to be present but you can always keep `layout` folder empty anyway, however this is not the best approach imho. I'd consider `layout` the **default** layout - but it is up to you if you put portrait or landscape layouts there (I'd suggest putting portrait) so in that case you need just `layout` and `layout-land`.

Comment: What if a device has a default layout of landscape?

Comment: then it will use `layout-land`

Comment: Are you sure? Why won't it use the default `layout`? Why is it bad practice to have only `-land` and `-port` considering these are the only two orientation?

Comment: Yes, I am sure. And it's bad because if you by any chance forget single file from either `-land` or `-port` while not having `layout` fallback, your app will simply crash due to missing layout